# Spring JDBC connection without dataSource

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I had read several articles on obtaining Connection using Spring DataSource.

But in our Company Setup, connection object is obtained through already configured environment. Following the sample code:

```
 String pool = PropertyFileReader.getPropertyValue("database.properties", "development.connectionPool");

    Connection connection = RequestUtils.getConnection(pool);
```

Hence, After reading this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LYqy0wvS20&feature=relmfu)

I am confused on using JDBCTemplate using connection object from above code.

Comment: Does I don't able to explain the question or problem properly?

Answer (score 3):

I believe JdbcTemplate is not designed to work against a Connection as what you expected.  As a workaround, if you are fine to create a separate JdbcTemplate for each connection you created, you may wrap your connection in a thin wrapper of DataSource, and feed it to JdbcTemplate.

I think it should work but I haven't tried it anyway...

```
class SingleConnectionDataSource implements DataSource {
    private Connection connection;
    public SingleConnectionDataSource(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
         return this.connection;
    }
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) {
         return this.connection;
    }
}

// at the place you want to use JdbcTemplate
Connection conn = blablabla;  // your own way to get it
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(conn));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Spring already provided SingleConnectionDataSource implementation (have seen in version 4.1.7).

It is even allows you to supress connection closing by template.